# How to add my other hard drives to ubuntu on vmware

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, vmware

I have Windows 8.1 as my main OS and can't change it because of homegroup for my family.  I installed VMware Workstation 11 and installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  I have shared my folders and have my D,E,F and G drives shared in vm settings but they are not showing up in my vm of ubuntu.  I know I am forgetting something but I can't figure it out as I am not familiar with linux.  I want to get to know it and access my other hard drives from the vm so my family can keep using the homegroup and I can use the vm version of ubuntu and everyone can be happy.  Thanks and please answer as detailed as possible as I'm not familiar with linux.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please  install samba in ubuntu for sharing access
By typing

> sudo apt-get install samba

And then go to network icon situated in (nautilus)home 
And add your host network by providing ip, hostname,  and password

Comment: Isn't there another way to do it in terminal that doesn't require me going through the network?  That's the way I did it last time.  Or is this way easier you think?

Comment: had something to do with vmhgfs

Answer (score 0):

One option is to share the files on the host that you want to access from VM, and then access them from the guest OS via the network, or by mounting the shared folder in Linux with "smbmount".

Here's some  ["Sharing Files Between Guest and Host Operating Systems on this from VMWare "](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws3/doc/ws32_running9.html) .